# Why calling size method on iterator pushes cursor to end?

Tags: scala

In below code I iterate over an iterator within an array and output is as expected :

```
val array = Array(List("1").iterator)     //> array  : Array[Iterator[String]] = Array(non-empty iterator)

    for(a <- array){
        //a.size
        for(element <- a){
            println(element)          //> 1
        }
    }
```

But if I add `a.size` it seems like this pushes the iterator cursor to end of collection as the iterator appears empty :

```
val array = Array(List("1").iterator)     //> array  : Array[Iterator[String]] = Array(non-empty iterator)

for(a <- array){
    a.size
    for(element <- a){
        println(element)
    }
}
```

Why is this occuring ? Checking the size of the elements should'nt have an impact on iteration of the collection ? Looking at the size method :

```
  def size: Int = {
    var result = 0
    for (x <- self) result += 1
    result
  }
```

It doesn't amend the iterator itself ?

These samples were tried in Scala worksheet

Comment: Because iterators are not about cursors, they are about consuming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because calling `.size` on an iterator requires it to iterate all of the elements in order to count them.

*edit* to elaborate:

An iterator has state: at any given point, calling its `next` function returns the next element and advances its state. In order to encounter all of the elements (e.g. to count them), it must call `next` until there are no more. At that point, its state is at the end, and therefore the iterator is no longer useful.

On a related note, see [TraversableOnce](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.TraversableOnce), a trait for things that you should only 'traverse' one time before they become useless. Iterator is one such thing.

Comment: reading the doc http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.TraversableOnce it states "A template trait for collections which can be traversed either once only or one or more times." which suggest such collections can be traversed more than once

Comment: Responding 5 years late - `TraversableOnce` is a general trait that pretty much every collection extends. Because `Traversable` extends `TraversableOnce`, it's possible to have a `TraversableOnce` that is *not* an instance of `Traversable`. Think of `Traversable` as the indication that you can traverse it multiple times. The docs you quoted are somewhat misleading in that sense.